# Propel - Joining the same table using multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, orm, schema, propel

I am having an issue with Propel2 (version 2.0.0-dev).

I have three foreign keys pointing to the same table:

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="sites" phpName="Site" refPhpName="Timesheet">
  <reference local="siteID" foreign="siteID"/>
</foreign-key>
<foreign-key foreignTable="sites" phpName="FromSite">
  <reference local="from_siteID" foreign="siteID"/>
</foreign-key>
<foreign-key foreignTable="sites" phpName="ToSite">
  <reference local="to_siteID" foreign="siteID"/>
</foreign-key>
```

and despite different PhpNames, the Base Class generates `default: $key` incorrectly:

```
if (null !== $this->aToSite) {
        switch ($keyType) {
            case TableMap::TYPE_CAMELNAME:
                $key = 'site';
                break;
            case TableMap::TYPE_FIELDNAME:
                $key = 'sites';
                break;
            default:
                $key = 'Site';
        }
        $result[$key] = $this->aToSite->toArray($keyType, $includeLazyLoadColumns,  $alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
    }
```

`default: $key` should be `ToSite`, not `Site`. Similarly for `FromSite`. As a result, the `Site` table is only joined for `Site`, but not for `FromSite` and `ToSite`, which subsequently doesn't allow me to call objects using `FromSite` and `ToSite`.

The tables are joined in the following way:

```
$timesheets = TimesheetQuery::create()
  ->select(Timesheet::getTransferFieldsWithRelations())
  ...
  ->joinWith("Timesheet.FromSite FromSite", Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
  ->joinWith("Timesheet.ToSite ToSite", Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
  ->joinWith("Timesheet.Site Site", Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
  ...
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to fix the above issue. In `Propel/Generator/Builder/Om/ObjectBuilder.php`, change the following:

```
if (\$includeForeignObjects) {";
        foreach ($fks as $fk) {
            $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getFKVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getForeignTable(), false)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getFKVarName($fk) . "->toArray(\$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns,  \$alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
        }";
        }
        foreach ($referrers as $fk) {
            if ($fk->isLocalPrimaryKey()) {
                $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getPKRefFKVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getTable(), false)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getPKRefFKVarName($fk) . "->toArray(\$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns, \$alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
        }";
            } else {
                $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getRefFKCollVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getTable(), true)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getRefFKCollVarName($fk) . "->toArray(null, false, \$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns, \$alreadyDumpedObjects);
        }";
            }
        }
        $script .= "
    }";
```

to

```
if (\$includeForeignObjects) {";
        foreach ($fks as $fk) {
            $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getFKVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getPhpName(), $fk->getForeignTable(), false)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getFKVarName($fk) . "->toArray(\$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns,  \$alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
        }";
        }
        foreach ($referrers as $fk) {
            if ($fk->isLocalPrimaryKey()) {
                $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getPKRefFKVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getRefPhpName(), $fk->getTable(), false)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getPKRefFKVarName($fk) . "->toArray(\$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns, \$alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
        }";
            } else {
                $script .= "
        if (null !== \$this->" . $this->getRefFKCollVarName($fk) . ") {
            {$this->addToArrayKeyLookUp($fk->getRefPhpName(), $fk->getTable(), true)}
            \$result[\$key] = \$this->" . $this->getRefFKCollVarName($fk) . "->toArray(null, false, \$keyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns, \$alreadyDumpedObjects);
        }";
            }
        }
        $script .= "
    }";
```

As well as this:

```
protected function addToArrayKeyLookUp(Table $table, $plural)
{
    $phpName = $table->getPhpName();
    $camelCaseName = $table->getCamelCaseName();
    $fieldName = $table->getName();
```

to:

```
protected function addToArrayKeyLookUp($phpName, Table $table, $plural)
{
    if($phpName == "") {
        $phpName = $table->getPhpName();  
    }

    $camelCaseName = $table->getCamelCaseName();
    $fieldName = $table->getName();
```

Now I can reference multiple FKs with PHPNames to the same table without any issues.

Note that the file will change every time Propel is updated.